# Creating object in database without showing view to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have controller with action `new`, and I want it to create ActiveRecord::Base descendant object, and write it into database (without showing it to user).

```
def new
  active_order = current_user.orders.find {|o| o.status > 0 }
  active_order = Order.new if active_order.nil?
  (...)
end
```

`Order.new` creates local object, but my question is -- how to make Rails to fill it with default values and write to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an unsaved ActiveRecord object instance to the database with the save method:

```
active_order = Order.new if active_order.nil?
active_order.save
```

It won't fill in the columns automatically, however. If you want to populate it with default values you can do this before calling save:

```
active_order = Order.new if active_order.nil?
active_order.field_name = "foo"
active_order.save
```

Or you can pass it in when you call new:

```
active_order = Order.new(:field_name => "foo") if active_order.nil?
active_order.save
```

If you want to do something fancier, you can have Rails automatically populate fields when you save by adding something like this to the model:

```
before_validation_on_create :set_default_values

def set_default_values
  field_name = "foo" if field_name.blank?
end
```

Comment: A shortcut to `active_order = Order.new if active_order.nil?` is `active_order ||= Order.new `.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Order.Create(...)` which will create a new object and persist it in the database (assuming Order is a child of ActiveBase of course)